# Playing Back Recorded Script

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm recording following user activity.

1.Login(Web Application)

2.User enters some fields in a form and saves it(This data goes into DB after saving)

stop recording...
Save the script.

Now, I'm playing back same script using only single Thread(virtual user).

I'm expecting same data to be entered by virtual user into DB but its not happening, no data is found in DB.

Tool used-JMETER.

I'm using SAMPLER-Http Request, Login Controller-Transaction Controller, Script Recorder and View Result Tree in Workbench to record.

My only Question is, Is it possible to enter data in DB by playing back same script using virtual user ?.

If yes, than how ?

Comment: It surely is possible. Can you check the application log for some proof that the services are really called? What about some unique constraints preventing the same data to be stored?

Comment: I just wanted to know that playing back recorded script with virtual user will do the same thing successfully(like data to be inserted in DB after saving). And yes you confirmed it .Thanks for reply as Jmeter users are very less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably failed to correlate some dynamic data or didn't use a Cookie Manager.

Ensure your record using jmeter > templates> Recording

and once done, ensure you correlate any dynamic id using Extractors and variables (google this for more details)

Comment: I knew, I'll have to use elements like POST PROCESSOR, COOKIE MANAGER, REGEX EXTRACTOR, ASSERTION and of course some listeners. But my question is, Is it possible to enter data in DB by playing back same script using virtual user ?........  thanks is advance

Comment: of course it is, sinve you're reproducing the application usage which does it.

Comment: Ok, now I'll positively continue doing this.

Comment: I am satisfied with the answer thus upvoted but as i am new it will be upvoted after earning 15 reputation.